# Configure a debugger process for a well known executable in the Windows registry

Tags: winapi, debugging, registry

There's a place in the registry where I can configure a debugger per process name. e.g. I can configure that whenever "chrome.exe" is run, then Windows should actually invoke some other process like "windbg.exe" with "chrome.exe" as its parameter.

I've done this in the past but I can't for the life of me remember where it was configured in the registry. I tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you've configured it properly?

ImageFile Execution option has some changes for 64-bit Windows and process. Please [see this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx)